# Mongodb - Updating nested object array without loosing attributes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How do I update or if not existent create a nested object array with one query? The update should only touch existing properties.

So I have a documents structure like this:

```
[
 {
  _id: ObjectId("61c296c1fe6de82e5eafd9e1"),
  id: 1235,
  name: 'Package',
  type: 'product',
  exampleOuter: 'test1',
  size: [
    {
      length: '10cm',
      height: '13cm',
      exampleInner: 'test2',
    },
    {
      length: '23cm',
      height: '15cm',
      exampleInner: 'test3',
    }
  ]
 }, 
...
]
```

I try to update this given object by the `id`. Lets assume I have a second object for ease lets call it: "`updateObject`" and I just want to update those fields from the original object that are existing in the `updateObject`. If the id is not found in the document than a new object from the updateObject should be created.

```
[
 {
  id: 1235,
  name: 'Package2',
  size: [
    {
      length: '20cm',
      height: '23cm'
    },
    {
      length: '33cm',
      height: '25cm'
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

The normal behavior of MongoDB is that the attributes `type`, `exampleOuter` are gone in the original object after performing this query since they are not existing in the `updateObject`. I prevent that from happening by using `$set`which looks like this: `{$set: updateObject}`. But this doesn't work for the object array in the size attribute. They are all loosing the `exampleInner` because it is not existing in the `updateObject`.

I first tried to wrap every object in the size array with a $set to achieve the desired behavior but obv that didn't work.

After reasearch i got the tip using the dot notation and an index. So my `updateObject` looks like this:

```
[
 {
  id: 1235,
  name: 'Package2',
  size.0.length: '20cm',
  size.0.height: '23cm',
  size.1.length: '33cm',
  size.1.height: '25cm',
 }
]
```

Which works fantastic for the update part but if the id of this new `updateObject` is not in the document than this will create a new object - which is correct but instead of an array of objects it will create an object with the index `0, 1,` ... as the key size.

So the new created document looks like this:

```
    size: {
      0: {
        length: '10cm',
      },
      1: {
        length: '23cm',
      }
    }
```

Am I on the right track with this or is there a complete other way to go? If it's the right approach how do I make sure that the if not existend objects the size attribute is created as an array and not as an object with the key as index?

Comment: You might try with `$addToSet` and `$each`

Comment: Please correct me if im wrong but if I add fields like the exampleInner or exampleOuter than if I use $addToSet it would just add the objects again since they are not found anymore